# What cables, mount kits and accessories to use with APC LCD KVM rack consoles?

Tags: keyboard-video-mouse

APC sells several rackmount LCD/mouse/keyboard KVM trays for server rack control. I’ve got an AP5719 and the USB keyboard doesn’t work with a standard VGA cable, because the built-in USB connector at the back of the device is only a pass through to the front connector for e.g. a USB stick. The built-in keyboard and mouse are somehow routed through the VGA connector – but what cable to use for that?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the entire series of APC LCD KVMs all use the same cables – they have a green overmold on the KVM side, and a blue one on the device side (server or a chained switch).

The following rackmount LCD KVM models all use the same cables:

- AP5808
- AP5816
- AP5717, AP5717CH, AP5717F, AP5717G, AP5717J, AP5717R, AP5717UK
- AP5719

The integrated KVM USB VGA cables are:

- AP5821 – 6 ft (1.8 m)
- AP5822 – 10 ft (3 m)
- AP5823 – 17 ft (5 m)

The integrated KVM PS/2 VGA cables are:

- AP5264 – 3 ft (0.9 m)
- AP5250 – 6 ft (1.8 m)
- AP5254 – 12 ft (3.6 M)
- AP5258 – 25 ft (7.6 m)

The KVM daisy chain cables for use with KVM switches only (AP5808, AP5816) are:

- AP5262 – 2 ft (0.6 m)
- AP5263 – 6 ft (1.8 m)

If you’re missing the rear rail-mount supports for the AP57xx family, then you need:

- KVM-LCDMOUNT – rear mounting kit for 2G (2nd generation) APC LCD KVM. This kit also allows to attach a 2G APC KVM Switch to 
  the rackmount LCD, without using additional rack space.

It is unknown to me at this time what is the part# and the pinout of the firmware upgrade cable for AP5717 and AP5719.